# Correct subproperty relation of OWL data properties

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I'm building an ontology and I need to create the same semantic relation (the name of the relation is the same as well as the meaning in the domain) between different classes of elements. For example:

```
 o:ClassA o:hasSemanticRelation xsd:string 
 o:ClassB o:hasSemanticRelation xsd:string
 o:ClassC o:hasSemanticRelation xsd:string
```

My first approach was to create multiple domains for the property but this actually means the intersection of the concepts which is not correct in the domain. 
My second approach was to have a super property

```
 owl:Thing o:hasSemanticRelation xsd:string
 o:hasSemanticRelationA owl:subPropertyOf o:hasSemanticRelation
 o:ClassA o:hasSemanticRelationA xsd:string
```

Because of the meaning of the *hasSemanticRelation* I want that every time it is used it can be linked to the same property, i.e., `o:hasSemanticRelation`

Could anyone give ideas how can I best represent this situation?

Comment: Your first code means domain and range of the property? I'm asking because it's confusing when you write it as triples.

Comment: Yes, it means domain and range of the property.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you're trying to do with a union of classes for the domain; so that instead of multiple domains (which is equivalent to domain intersection) you'd have one single domain which is a union. This can be named or unnamed, depending on your requirements.